# I want to Convert a UTC Time into local time by giving specific location using golang

Tags: go

I am a golang developer and i am trying to convert a UTC time into local  time  but my code not working.Here is my code

```
utc := time.Now().UTC()
local := utc
location, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Delhi")
if err == nil {
   local = local.In(location)
}
log.Println("UTC", utc.Format("15:04"), local.Location(), local.Format("15:04"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC to "local" time - Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318154/convert-utc-to-local-time-go)

Comment: Replace `Asia/Delhi` with `Asia/Calcutta`. Refer [this](https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go)

Answer (score 4):

You should rewrite your code to handle errors when they occur. The default execution path should be error free. So, after `time.LoadLocation` check if there is an error:

```
utc := time.Now().UTC()
local := utc
location, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Delhi")
if err != nil {
   // execution would stop, you could also print the error and continue with default values
   log.Fatal(err)
}
local = local.In(location)
log.Println("UTC", utc.Format("15:04"), local.Location(), local.Format("15:04"))
```

Now you'll get something like this error message:

```
cannot find Asia/Delhi in zip file /usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip
panic: time: missing Location in call to Time.In
```

You have to find a valid time zome for your location, as others said check Wikipedia for [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an error on line 3, you just can't see it because it avoids the `if` block and so never updates the `local` variable on line 5.

The reason it fails is because 'Asia/Delhi' is not a valid olsen format.

Add an `else` block and print out the `err.Error()` value

See the following link for a list of valid formats:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: i got expected result when i using  location "Asia/Calcutta".Is there is any other method for this by providing latitude and longitude of a location @Gov

Comment: There are a number of ways to find the data from lat/long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

This is just converting UTC time string to your local time string according to your specified layout.

```
func UTCTimeStr2LocalTimeStr(ts, layout string) (string, error) {                                                                  
    timeObject, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, ts)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return time.Unix(timeObject.Unix(), 0).Format(layout), nil
}
```